# SQL Server : row-level security on table not enforced within another predicate function

Tags: sql-server, row-level-security

Consider the following: there are two tables, table A and table B. Implement RLS on table A.

Then, on table B implement RLS by linking table B to table A thru an inner join.
Guess what, within the predicate function for table B the RLS for table A is ignored.

1. It appears, you need to reapply the RLS for table A in the predicate function for table B. Is this by design?
2. Is there some flag or "with" clause that can be set to enforce existing RLS when linking table B to table A within predicate function?
3. Am I doing something wrong?

SQL script to create & populate the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Securities]
(
    [SecurityId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Security] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IssueCurrency] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Securities] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SecurityId] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Prices]
(
    [SecurityId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriceDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [numeric](18, 4) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Prices] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SecurityId] ASC, [PriceDate] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Prices] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Prices_Securities] 
        FOREIGN KEY([SecurityId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Securities] ([SecurityId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Prices] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Prices_Securities]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Securities] ([SecurityId], [Security], [IssueCurrency])
VALUES (1, 'Project Power', 'CAD'), (2, 'Fractured Ltd', 'AUD'),
       (5, 'Eddy Security', 'USD'), (6, 'Foxtrot', 'USD')
GO

INSERT INTO Prices ([SecurityId], [PriceDate], [Price])
VALUES (1, '2020-08-05', 13.2500), (1, '2020-08-06', 13.3500), (1, '2020-08-07', 13.0500),
       (2, '2020-08-05', 23.9500), (2, '2020-08-06', 24.1500), (2, '2020-08-07', 22.0500),
       (5, '2020-08-05', 105.1500), (5, '2020-08-06', 106.3500), (5, '2020-08-07', 105.0500),
       (6, '2020-08-05', 36.2500), (6, '2020-08-06', 36.3500), (6, '2020-08-07', 35.0500)
```

SQL Script to create predicate function & security policy.

```
/*
drop security policy if exists Policy_Securities
go 

drop function if exists dbo.rlsSecurities
go
*/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION rlsSecurities (@IssueCurrency varchar(3))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN 
    SELECT 1 AS UserAccess
        WHERE
            (SESSION_CONTEXT(N'UserGroup') = 'Internal')  or
            (
                @IssueCurrency = 'USD'      --non-internal group can only view securities where IssueCurrency='USD'         
            )
go

CREATE SECURITY POLICY Policy_Securities
ADD FILTER PREDICATE dbo.rlsSecurities(IssueCurrency) ON dbo.Securities
WITH(STATE = ON)
go

EXEC sys.sp_set_session_context @key=N'UserGroup', @value='XYZ'

SELECT SESSION_CONTEXT(N'UserGroup')

SELECT * FROM Securities

SELECT s.Security, p.*
FROM Securities s
INNER JOIN Prices p ON s.SecurityId = p.SecurityId  --RLS on table Prices is enforced thru inner join.

SELECT * FROM Prices  --Currently no RLS on tblComp.
```

```
--Now I want to implement RLS on Prices as well.
drop security policy if exists Policy_Prices
go 

drop function if exists dbo.rlsPrices
go

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create FUNCTION rlsPrices (
    @SecurityId int)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN 

    SELECT 1 as UserAccess
        where @SecurityId in (select SecurityId from dbo.Securities)  --This doesn't work even though RLS on table Securities already exists.
        
        --where   --This works but it requires reapplying RLS on table Securities.
        --  (SESSION_CONTEXT(N'UserGroup') = 'Internal')  or
        --  (
        --      @SecurityId In (select SecurityId from dbo.Securities where IssueCurrency = 'USD')      --non-internal group can only view securities where IssueCurrency='USD'         
        --  )
go

CREATE SECURITY POLICY Policy_Prices
ADD FILTER PREDICATE dbo.rlsPrices(SecurityId) ON dbo.Prices
WITH(STATE = ON)

go
exec sys.sp_set_session_context @key=N'UserGroup', @value='XYZ'
select SESSION_CONTEXT(N'UserGroup')
select * from Prices    --RLS not enforced
```

Comment: This starts off reading like a homework question, is it? You show your attempts, which is good, but if it is homework we shouldn't be writing the answer for you and should be showing and explaining why what you have doesn't work. This also *might* be better on [dba.se] due to its focus on Row Level Security.

Comment: @Larnu  No, not a homework question. Haven't had to do homework in nearly 25 years. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong.

It seems RLS does not take into consideration any existing policies on the tables referenced in the predicate table-valued function **when the tvf is executed in the scope/enforcement of a policy**.
The tvf works fine when executed in a normal query (the policy of referenced table {ie. Securities} in the tvf is enforced):

```
--standalone...check the execution plan, predicate of Securities.PK_Securities index scan is the function/policy on currency='USD'
select p.* 
from Prices as p
cross apply dbo.rlsPrices(p.SecurityId)
```

If you check the execution plan for:

```
--filter policy on Prices
select * from Prices
```

You will only see a clustered index scan on Prices, since there is a FK from Prices to Securities (SecurityId) the securities table is not checked at all.
Even if you remove the FK, the join between Prices & Securities misses any RLS predicate on Securities.

In short, filter policies are not nested/inherited/cascaded, whether by design or not .. it is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for your input...appreciated it! I'm going to assume it is by design.